# Renaming a website inside Default Web Site on windows IIS server

Tags: laravel, windows, iis

I want to rename website present inside Default Web Site. On right clicking the app it does not have any rename option. Kindly suggest how to rename it.

Comment: Add a new one and then remove the old one.

Answer (score 5):

You can rename the website by changing the "path" in applicationHost.config.

The applicationHost.config file in this path:  C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config.

```
<application path="/rename" applicationPool="test1"></application>
```